# Mapear string en una fecha aun si es null C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Tengo un `string` que se guarda en forma `"2019-06-12"`

Resulta que tengo esta clase:

```
public class ReverseModelView
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Material { get; set; }
        public string NumParte { get; set; }
        public string NombreMaterialUnion { get; set; }
        public string NombreMaterial { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Aprobado { get; set; }
        public string Aros { get; set; }
        public string Revision { get; set; }
        public string Diametro { get; set; }
        public string Largo { get; set; }
        public string Top { get; set; }
        public string Bottom { get; set; }
        public string Otras { get; set; }
        public string UniCajas { get; set; }
        public string OrdenEmitida { get; set; }
        public string ClienteFinal { get; set; }
    }
```

En la cual mapeo los datos utilizando esto:

```
var listadoReversibles = clienteServicio.DatosReverse();
 List<ReverseModelView> reverseMap = new List<ReverseModelView>();

        foreach(var item in listadoReversibles)
        {
            ReverseModelView _item = new ReverseModelView();
            _item.Id = item.Id;
            _item.Material = item.Material;
            _item.NumParte = item.NumParte;
            _item.NombreMaterialUnion = item.Material_Nombre;
            _item.NombreMaterial = item.NombreMaterial;
            _item.Aprobado = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Aprobado, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            _item.Aros = item.Aros;
            _item.Revision = item.Revision;
            _item.Diametro = item.Diametro;
            _item.Largo = item.Largo;
            _item.Top = item.Top;
            _item.Bottom = item.Bottom;
            _item.Otras = item.Otras;
            _item.UniCajas = item.UniCajas;
            reverseMap.Add(_item);
        }
```

La variables `_item.Aprobado` es un string donde guardo las fechas (como tal puede ser nulo), entonces a la hora de guardar la fecha en `item.Aprobado` (que este si es un `DateTime`) me sale el siguiente error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Referencia a cadena no establecida como
>   una instancia de cadena.'

Como puedo guardar la fecha en modo `"MM-dd-yyyy"` y si es nulo pues que guarde el nulo igual?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar algo como:

```
// Si item.aprobado es nulo, vacío o espacios en blanco entonces, 
// devolver una cadena vacía (ojo no nula si quieres nulo cambia por null)
// de lo contrario devuelve el DateTime.Parse.
_item.Aprobado = String.IsNullOrWhitespace(item.aprobado) ? String.Empty : DateTime.Parse(.........);
```

Sin embargo, no te libra que `item.aprobado` contenga una fecha inválida. Otra posibilidad es que utilices DateTime.TryParseExact(...).

```
// Ojo al formato le quite  la hora ya que tu fecha viene sin esta.
If(!DateTime.TryParseExact(item.Aprobado, "MM/dd/yyyy ", DateTimeStyles.none, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out _item.Aprobado) {
    _item.Aprobado = null;    
}
```

Comment: la segunda respuesta es la correcta sin embargo creo que seria mejor un metodo de extensión